# Add values of object in array - javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

This is my response data:

```
var data = [{
                'name': 'ragu',
                'taxprice': '20'
            } {
                'name': 'ram',
                'taxprice': '20'
            } {
                'name': 'sandy',
                'taxprice': '20'
            } {
                'name': 'ramu',
                'taxprice': '20'
            }];
```

I want to add the all the taxprice value

my expected result is  subtotal = 80

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Answer (score 7):

Use ([Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce))

```js
var data = [{'name': 'ragu', 'taxprice': '20' }, {'name': 'ram', 'taxprice': '20'}, {'name': 'sandy', 'taxprice': '20'}, { 'name': 'ramu', 'taxprice': '20'}];
                
var result = data.reduce((a,c) => a + Number(c.taxprice), 0);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Many dupes here.

Comment: Agreed but with conversion to number may be hard to find. Hence, added the solution.